# Wrong number of arguments in as_json [`timeout` method is reserved!]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get an error in Rails that is related to one of my models, let's call it `Unit`. The following code produces an error:

```
format.json { render :json => @units.as_json }
```

The error is about wrong number of parameters (0 of 1).

Comment: what's the backtrace for the error?

Comment: First try completely commenting out an 'as_json' you have defined in the model. Rails will create one by default so you don't really need one. If the default json generated doesn't meet your needs, then you can create your own to customize it.

Comment: @KevinBedell Commented out, still the same error.

Comment: In the rails console, try `foo = Unit.first` and then `foo.to_json` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. From the Rails source:

```
  module Serialization
    def serializable_hash(options = nil)
      options ||= {}

      attribute_names = attributes.keys.sort
      if only = options[:only]
        attribute_names &= Array.wrap(only).map(&:to_s)
      elsif except = options[:except]
        attribute_names -= Array.wrap(except).map(&:to_s)
      end

      hash = {}
      attribute_names.each { |n| hash[n] = read_attribute_for_serialization(n) } # exception here

      # ...
    end

    alias :read_attribute_for_serialization :send

    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

So the real error is that one of the methods returned by calling e.g. `Unit.first.attributes.keys.sort` (`["dev_id", "flags", "id", "inote", "ip", "location_id", "model_id", "name", "period", "phone", "port", "snote", "timeout"]`) expects me to pass an argument to it. This method is `timeout`, it is some private method Rails monkey patches Object with. So the correct solution to the problem is to rename this attribute to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is;

```
def scheme
  @object = MonitoringObject.restricted_find params[:id], session[:client]

  @units = Unit.where("object_id = ?", @object.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @units[0] }
  end
end
```

Or, if you have your relationships set up between the `MonitoringObject` and `Unit` models correctly,

```
def scheme
  @object = MonitoringObject.restricted_find params[:id], session[:client]
  @units = @object.units

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @units[0] }
  end
end
```

You're supplying it with an `:except` parameter that's empty.

You'll use an `:except` condition if there are some attributes you don't want included in the JSON response.

According to the [rails guide on views and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), you don't need to specify `.to_json` -- it will be called for you automatically.

It looks to me that the problem may lie in your `.restricted_find` method somewhere. Can you post the entire stack trace )or link to a github gist that contains it?

Comment: I put the whole action method in my updated question. After I removed .as_json, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the question with DRYer code and some logs attached.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. It was kind of obscured by things, but ultimately it's my unwillingness to read into the stack frame that costed me so much time.