# Ruby on rails to_json error wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a bunch of objects I'm trying to update every few seconds. Every once in a while the action I'm polling that is supposed to return @array.to_json dies with that error - wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

I've seen this might happen with some objects containing attributes Rails is using internally but I can't find anything suspicious

Data sample:

```
{"prop": {"match_id": 4295119908, "title": "Draw", "status": 1, "prop_type_id": 36, "market_id": 111363650, "id": 127503900, "source": 1, "selection_id": 58805, "odds": 1.52}}
```

What is strange is that it doesn't happen all the time. If i refresh the page several times, only one out of 5 or 10 requests fails.

Can someone help? Would there be something else that might be causing this error?

TIA

Full error:

```
    /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:75:in `[]='
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:75:in `send'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:75:in `serializable_record'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:75:in `each'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:75:in `serializable_record'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/misc.rb:39:in `returning'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:74:in `serializable_record'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serializers/json_serializer.rb:70:in `serialize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:91:in `to_s'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/serializers/json_serializer.rb:57:in `to_json'
app/views/props/load_props2.html.erb:46
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in `send'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in `render'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/template.rb:73:in `render_template'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:256:in `render'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1174:in `render_for_file'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:896:in `render_without_benchmark'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:8:in `realtime'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:868:in `render_without_benchmark'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:8:in `realtime'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1248:in `default_render'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1254:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:136:in `perform_action_without_caching'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:13:in `passenger_orig_perform_action'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in `cache'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:12:in `passenger_orig_perform_action'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/request_handler.rb:66:in `perform_action'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `send'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `process_without_filters'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_without_session_management_support'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:134:in `process'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:392:in `process'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:183:in `handle_request'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:110:in `dispatch_unlocked'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:123:in `dispatch'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `synchronize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in `dispatch_cgi'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in `dispatch'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/request_handler.rb:51:in `process_request'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

The code (line 45) is

`@propz.to_json`

@propz is an array of data as per above

Comment: Please post the actual code that's causing the problem. Also please post the full error message - there's usually a receiving object involved.

Comment: maybe debugging can clarify the issue?

Comment: Well I've seen this post here from a guy having the same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431077/wrong-number-of-arguments-in-as-json-timeout-method-is-reserved - but I can't find any attributes that might cause a problem with the framework. Maybe source or status? But these are quite usual, common sense says it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: if you're not dealing with model objects, just hashes and arrays you could forego `to_json` all together and use MultiJson

Comment: Do you have a custom `to_json` method on your model?

Comment: No. Just using what came with Rails

Comment: Turns out I had to do this require "multi_json" and then MultiJson.engine = :ok_json. This was really strange and took a while to figure out. When in production mode, multi-json was kicking in with a different engine than in development mode, so the code was actually working only in dev mode. Now I still can't figure out why the json gems don't like the objects I'm trying to serialize. They're not ActiveRecord objects, maybe that's why? Although it would be silly, one should be able to encode/serialize pretty much anything